# How Can i fix Syncfusion SfListView example problem?

Tags: c#, listview, syncfusion

#### When i compile the code , i'm getting those two errors:

CS0103  The name 'GetDataSource' does not exist in the current context

```
//form1.cs//

using Syncfusion.WinForms.ListView;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using countryInfo;

namespace Listveiw
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           // SfListView sfListView1 = new SfListView();
           // sfListView1.Location = new Point(100, 100);
            //sfListView1.Size = new Size(300, 320);
           this.Controls.Add(sfListView1);
            sfListView1.DataSource =GetDataSource();
            sfListView1.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
            sfListView1.ValueMember = "Continent";
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void sfListView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}

//Class1.cs//
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace countryInfo
{
    public class CountryInfo
    {
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string Continent { get; set; }
        public string GetDataSource { get; set; }
       


        public List<CountryInfo> GetDataSource()
        {
            List<CountryInfo> countryInfoCollection = new List<CountryInfo>();
            countryInfoCollection.Add(new CountryInfo() { CountryName = "China", Continent = "Asia" });
            countryInfoCollection.Add(new CountryInfo() { CountryName = "India", Continent = "Asia" });
          return countryInfoCollection;
      }
  }
}
```

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/susjg.png) 
This an example code from Synfusion.You can find the codes and relevant instructions here: https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/listview/gettingstarted

Comment: You defined a variable with the name GetDataSource in your CountryInfo. And you have a method called GetDataSource. There's the conflict.